# jquery dialog window opens with datepicker text already focused

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, dialog

I know this is a tough one to understand....

I have a button that opens a dialog window.  The buildPurchaseOrder url is just a form.

```
    $('#poDialog').dialog({
        width:1000,
        height:1000,
        modal:true,
        autoOpen: false,
        close: function(event, ui) { 
            $('#poDialog').dialog('close');
        } 
    })

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:{'items' : items,
              '_token' : token},
        url:"buildPurchaseOrder",
        success:function(result){

            $('#poDialog').dialog('open');
            $('#poDialog').html(result);
        }
    })
```

The relevant part of the form:

```
 <input type='text' id='requestedDate' class='datePicker'>
```

In that dialog window I have a input text that has datepicker on it.

```
    $('body').on('focus',".datePicker", function(){
        $(this).datepicker({
        });
    });
```

The first time i click on the button to open dialog, it works fine.
If i close the dialog with the upper right corner x and open the dialog again, The input text datepicker is already focused and clicking dates does not work:

(error: jquery-ui.js:8188 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'currentDay')).

This is what is seen when i clicked on the button to open the dialog on the second time i open dialog. I havent clicked/focused on anything yet.  What other info might be needed to help figure out why the datepicker is already focused when dialog loads?  I know there's a lot going on here that you can't see.  I have verified that the id is not duplicated anywhere.  What else should i be looking at?

[image]

Comment: Curious why you are initializing datepicker on focus and not before; then simply open the datepicker on focus.

Comment: how would i do that before?

Comment: once the HTML is loaded into the Dialog, you can then initialize datepicker on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```
$('#poDialog').dialog({
  width: 1000,
  height: 1000,
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  close: function(event, ui) {
    $('#poDialog').dialog('close');
  }
})

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    'items': items,
    '_token': token
  },
  url: "buildPurchaseOrder",
  success: function(result) {
    $('#poDialog').html(result).dialog('open');
    $('#poDialog .datepicker').datepicker().focus();
  }
})
```

When the AJAX call completes, HTML will be loaded into the Dialog window. Now you initialize DatePicker upon the element.

**Update**

Another example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#poDialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
      $("#requestedDate").datepicker().focus();
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
      $('#poDialog').dialog('close');
    }
  });

  $("#create-date").click(function() {

    $('#poDialog').html("<form><label>Requested Dates</label><input type='text' id='requestedDate' class='datePicker'><textarea placeholder='Notes...'></textarea></form>").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="poDialog" title="New Request"></div>


<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
  <h1>Requested Dates:</h1>
  <table id="dates" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
      <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
        <th>Requested Date</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="create-date">Create new Date</button>
```